# Populate URL Parameter with Logged in User Name

Tags: url, parameters, url-parameters

How to populate an url parameter with the user name of the person that is logged into my site?  For example: in the url 
https://www.example.com/somethinghere?sid=   I am needing to find a way to populate the username of the person logged in after sid.  So let's say my username is **bigred** and I'm logged into my site, how do I go about having the url show https://www.example.com/somethinghere?sid=**bigred**

Comment: Not enough information.  We need to at least know what sort of server environment you're running (i.e. Java, PHP, static HTML, etc.).  And also this approach seems ill-advised (depending upon what you plan on using the parameter for on the server-side).  What stops me from copy/pasting the URL, entering another person's username, and then accessing their account?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie at this.  My page is in a PHP environment.  The sid will only be used for reporting purposes only when someone completes a task so I can know exactly who completed the task to award them with a prize.  I could use the id number assigned to the user instead.

Comment: Just to add, the only time the parameter would be populated is when a person is logged into the site.  And also, the only page that would have the information would require the user to be logged in.  So, I don't think there would be a security issue to where a person could copy/pasting the URL, entering another person's username, and then accessing their account.

Comment: I think it would be much more appropriate to store this information as part of the HTTP session, rather than passing it around as a parameter in the URL.  For instance, when the user logs in you can set `$_SESSION['sid'] = 'bigred'` in your code.  Here's some additional information:  http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions_2.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I got it to work by using a print function with the logged in user session.  Much appreciate!

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I got it to work by using a print function with the logged in user session.  Much appreciate!